java. lang. AssertionError: 1 expectation failed. JSON path id doesn't match. Expected: 167039 but actual is an array
Hi i have created this function.
@Test
    public void getStatus() {

        given()
                .when()
                .get("https://gorest.co.in/public/v2/posts")
                .then()
                .statusCode(200)
                .body("id",equalTo("167039"))
                .header("User-Agent","application/json");


    }
}

but getting this error
java. lang. AssertionError: 1 expectation failed. JSON path id doesn't match. Expected: 167039 Actual: <[167452, 167451, 167449, 167448, 167447, 167446, 167417, 167416, 167413, 167412]>
i am trying to access single id record.

Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! This code is RestAssure, right? You should tag it as such. The JSON body does not contain any id with value 167039. And "application/json" is certainly not a common User-Agent

"https://gorest.co.in/public/v2/posts"
This returns a list of posts. So it doesn't have id as a parameter.
Try using .body("find { it.id == 167039 }.id", equalTo(167039))
